# Package dependencies and initialization

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and trying to find a solution to the following problem.

1. The goal is to write all logs to a file.
2. package main imports package A.
3. In package main, in the main method, logging is setup to write to a file
4. package A has an init function. In the init function of A, there is a log line - log.Fatal("I am package A").
5. Since main package imports A, A's init function is first called (even before we get a chance to setup the logs to write to a file).

How to resolve this so the log "I am package A" gets written to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move logging initialization out to a `log` package that is imported by both `main` and `A` and does not depend directly or indirectly on the parts of your app that you want to log to the file during initialization. From the descriptions of init order in [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#initialization) and [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution), that should be enough to make sure your logging is initialized first thing.

Comment: Thanks! If I extract to the log package, since I want to use it in multiple projects, I will put it in a common location (accessible by all projects). I then want to pass in a parameter to a function of the log package and set the filename to log to. I run into a problem again then because package A is logging on its init function but by the time I set the filename on the log, package A has already logged.

Comment: Yeah, if each project sets its own log location, the loc.-setting code has to run first, which kind of leads you towards a `log` package per project. Alternately, a single `log` package could choose location based on program name (os.Args[0]) or environment or a log config file or something else global. If you want to get super crazy, `log` could log to a `bytes.Buffer` or temp file until configured, then copy everything to the "real" log once its location is determined. I can't really recommend that last option though--either have a single `log` package pick a file or fork `log` per project.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the pointers. I guess the command line arguments or environment variables is the way to go (forking into every project doesn't sound appealing from a change management perspective). I would have guessed the same thing with my current knowledge of go, but since I am brand new to go programming, I wanted to check if there is some easy way I didn't know of.

Answer (score 0):

If the init function of package A depends on something else being done, the *only* place in which that something else can be put is in the init function of a package depended on by A. If you want to be able to parametrize that something else, you need to move everything out of `init` and into manually-called functions (call them `CustomInit` or something) for which you can control the call order, parameters, etc.

Basically, you can't have parametrized init functions. Since A's init function logs to a parametrized logging object, that makes it (indirectly) parametrized, so you can't use the built-in `init` function for that.

Comment: What you suggest is doable if we have full control on everything, but with third party packages, we hardly have control (unless of-course we rip it open and inspect every file of every package). Third party packages could very well use log package to log within init. I don't know if its bad practice and whether third party packages usually avoid doing things like logging from init functions. The only option seems to be a per project log package or a command line argument/env variable. There are some weird situations like this with go where it stumps you.

Comment: I would think that generally logging from init is a bad practice - there shouldn't be much worth logging from there anyways, and there's no (easy) way to control where it logs to. I would be suspicious of any third-party package that logs from init.